# Diagnosing Blue Screen (IRQL_not_less_or_equal) Windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, bsod

I've searched high and low for an answer to this one. I recently removed my nVidia graphics card and the crashes are now less frequent. Here's the info from my latest mini dump. Can anybody shed any light on this?

Thanks!

==================================================
Dump File         : 032413-14320-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 24/03/2013 22:55:22
Bug Check String  : IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000000a
Parameter 1       : fffffd80`04695fe8
Parameter 2       : 00000000`00000002
Parameter 3       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 4       : fffff800`029669d5
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+75c40
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7601.18044 (win7sp1_gdr.130104-1431)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+75c40
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\032413-14320-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 4
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601

## Dump File Size    : 280,944

Comment: upload the file 032413-14320-01.dmp to your skydrive, dropbox and add a link to your question. I'll try to look at it with WinDbg.

Answer (score 0):

I would start at the very beginning in scenario like this because these BSOD messages can sometimes be misleading and can easily send you down the wrong path.

Test your hard drive for bad sectors as well as the RAM in your system for errors.

There are a variety of bootable disk utilities you can use to test the health of Hard Drives. One simple but effective tool to use is [Drive Fitness Test](http://www.hgst.com/support/downloads/#DFT). This will tool will essentially go through the drive checking for bad sectors as well as performing a number of other checks in the process.

The second thing to test for would be faulty RAM, with something like [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/).

Once you have established that there is no faulty hardware it will be much easier to diagnose other, OS related issues, such as faulty drivers or bad patches/processes.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your response. Unfortunately Drive Fitness Test doesn't allow me to run it on my primary drive and there doesn't seem to be anything there to allow me to boot with the program. I'll try the Memtest and see how that goes. All the equipment in the PC is brand new which is why this is so frustrating! Thanks.

Comment: Should have asked prior to posting, is this an SSD or a spinning drive?  Sometimes there are settings in the bios that you need to adjust for the drive to be seen by DFT.